# Help with summation Σ

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I have an example in the book:

> $$\frac{i -1 }{ i}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac{j}{i}=1-\frac{1}{i}+\frac{i-1}{2}=\frac{i}{2}-\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{2}$$

I am not sure how is the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: $\;\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} j =\frac{i(i-1)}{2}\,$.

Comment: @ Rain [This page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help you learn how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ so you can more clearly write your questions, being able to write things like $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1}\dfrac{j}{i}$ and avoid poor formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j=\frac12i(i-1)}$.  Hence,

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{\frac{i-1}{i}}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac{j}{i}&=\color{red}{\frac{i-1}{i}}+\color{blue}{\frac12}\frac{\color{blue}{i(i-1)}}{i}\\\\
&=\color{red}{1-\frac1i} +\frac{i}{2}-\frac12\\\\
&=\frac{i}{2}-\frac1i+\frac12
\end{align}$$